# How to access the objects inside an unnamed array json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an json response from a link and when I call the $http.get function to get the data. The values which I'm trying to get are placed inside unnamed arrays.

The json response:

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#gaData",
  "rows": [
    [
      "Windows",
      "28514"
    ],
    [
      "Android",
      "6473"
    ],
    [
      "iOS",
      "4011"
    ],
    [
      "Macintosh",
      "846"
    ],
    [
      "Linux",
      "752"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm using angular functions $http.get but I don't know how to access those values Windows -> 28514

at the javascript momentally I'm just trying to get those objects before doing anything with them so I'm just passing them into console.

```
$http.get('https://radiopendimi-woosh.appspot.com/query?id=ahRzfnJhZGlvcGVuZGltaS13b29zaHIVCxIIQXBpUXVlcnkYgICAgPiJjAoM').then(function(data){
          console.log(data.rows);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the array:

```
$http.get('https://radiopendimi-woosh.appspot.com/query?id=ahRzfnJhZGlvcGVuZGltaS13b29zaHIVCxIIQXBpUXVlcnkYgICAgPiJjAoM').then(function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++;) {
        console.log(data.rows[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the `rows` array into an object:

```
var lookup = data.rows.reduce(function(out, pair) {
    out[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    return out;
}, {})
```

Then `lookup` will be something like this:

```
{
  "Windows": "28514",
  "Android": "6473",
  "iOS": "4011",
  "Macintosh": "846",
  "Linux": "752"
}
```

And you can access by name:

```
lookup.Windows
> 28514
```

Comment: there are no associative arrays in javascript...that is an object literal